# On last digit of 4 consecutive primes less than 10 apart

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$\def\mod{\mathrm{\;mod\;}}\def\pq{\{p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4\}}$$\def\dq{\{d_1,d_2,d_3,d_4\}}$
This question concerns quartets of consecutive primes $p_1 < p_2 < p_3 < p_4$ such that $p_4 - p_1 < 10$, and the associated quartets $\dq$ consisting of the last decimal digit of each of the $p_i$.

For example, if $\pq = \{11,13,17,19\}$, then $\dq = \{1,3,7,9\}$.

*Assuming my code is correct* (i.e. no bugs), then among the primes $< 10^8$ there are only three such quartets of primes whose associated quartets of last digits is *not* $\{1,3,7,9\}$.  These three quartets are:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\{2, 3, 5, 7\} \\
\{3, 5, 7, 11\} \\
\{5, 7, 11, 13\}
\end{array}
$$

Are these really the only ones?  If so, how does one prove it?

To state the question differently, let $x = 10\,n$ for some integer $n \geq 0$.  Consider the following (overlapping) quartets of odd positive integers:

$$
\begin{array}{llllllll}
\{& x+3, & x+7, & x+9, & x+11  &       &      &\} \\
\{&      & x+7, & x+9, & x+11, & x+13  &      &\} \\
\{&      &      & x+9, & x+11, & x+13, & x+17 &\}
\end{array}
$$

Can any *one* such quartet consist solely of prime numbers?

I have not been able to find one, but it's not immediately obvious to me why.

FWIW, at least in the range $[0, 10^8]$, there seems to be no shortage of positive integers $x = 10\,n$ such that the quartet $\{x+1, x+3, x+7, x+9\}$ consists solely of primes.  I found $4767$ such $x$, the smallest and largest ones being being $x = 10$ and $x = 99982240$.

Comment: Except $2$ and $5$, the last digit of a prime must be one of $1,3,7,9$. If four consecutive primes are less than $10$ apart, none of these last digits can occur more than once, so the set must be $\{1,3,7,9\}$. Now it remains to see that the smallest of the four primes must be of the form $10k+1$. You can eliminate the other cases by considering remainders modulo $3$.

Comment: After 3 and 5, all primes must be a multiple of 6 +/- 1.

Comment: If you can show there are infinitely many of these prime quartets, you will have proved the Twin Prime Conjecture. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you consider the additions to $x$ modulo $3$ within

$\begin{array}{llllllll}
\{& x+3, & x+7, & x+9, & x+11  &       &      &\} \\
\{&      & x+7, & x+9, & x+11, & x+13  &      &\} \\
\{&      &      & x+9, & x+11, & x+13, & x+17 &\}
\end{array}$

You get

$\begin{array}{llllllll}
\{& 0, & 1, & 0, & 2  &       &      &\} \\
\{&      & 1, & 0, & 2, & 1  &      &\} \\
\{&      &      & 0, & 2, & 1, & 2 &\}
\end{array}$

Since each row contains a $0$, a $1$ and a $2$, whatever $x$ is modulo $3$ each row will have a number divisible by $3$. So it either contains $3$ itself, or contains a composite number. The only way it can be $3$ is the first row, with $x = 0$ but that would make $x + 9 = 9$, so there's always a composite number.

Note however ${1,3,7,9} \equiv {1,0,1,0} \mod 3$, so the argument doesn't apply to that case.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, your argument looks incomplete to me, because, as far as I can tell, it covers only the case where $x$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $3$, whereas $x$ could also be congruent to $1$ (e.g. $x=10$) or to $2$ (e.g. $x = 20$) modulo $3$.

Comment: No because each row has a 0, a 1 and a 2, whatever $x$ is $\mod 3$ when you add it there will still be a 0, a 1 and a 2. If $x \equiv 1 \mod 3$ then the first row is 1,2,1,0 the second 2,1,0,1 and the third 1,0,2,0 - always a 0.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the clarifiication!

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear if you care about the order of the last-digits, but if you did not then the problem seems very trivial. So I will assume that you do want the order of the last-digits to respect the order of the consecutive primes.

Then Daniel Fischer's comment does this for you. If a last digit is $5$, then the entire prime is $5$, and we can identify $\{2,3,5,7\}, \{3,5,7,11\}$ and $\{5,7,11,13\}$ as solutions. Beyond this, we can rule out $5$ (and $2$) as a last digit.

Do you know that there are no triplet primes except $\{3,5,7\}$? Writing sets in ascending order, each of $\{\ldots3,\color{red}{\ldots7,\ldots9,\ldots1}\}, \{\color{red}{\ldots7,\ldots9,\ldots1},\ldots3\}, \{\color{red}{\ldots9,\ldots1,\ldots3},\ldots7\}$ that have diameter under $10$ would have to have triplet primes (indicated in red). So the only option left is $\{\ldots1,\ldots3,\ldots7,\ldots9\}$.